# Not being able to store a DocumentSnapshot in react-redux results in Maximum call stack size exceeded error while paging

Tags: react-native, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am building a react-native app. In this app, I am storing the last document (lastDoc) of a query result in redux and when the app is re-launched I use the persisted lastDoc as a starting point for a firestore query so that I can page the remaining firestore documents from where the user left off. I realized (after a Maximum call stack size exceeded error) that even though I send a document snapshot to be stored in the redux, the re-hydrated data is **Object** type, not QueryDocumentSnapshot and this breaks my **startAfter** query resulting in the aforementioned **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error.

Is there a way to store a document snapshot in react-redux? Or should I switch to using something like [redux-firestore](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore/pull/246)?

This is what I send to redux:

[image]

This is what gets re-hydrated from redux:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since you cannot store document snapshots in react-redux and since I did not want to switch to redux-firestore which would probably result in changes in my codebase that I don't want to go through at this stage, I came up with this alternative solution.

After getting my records from firestore backend, I get the last document in the fetched query snapshot and add to it the document's id like so:

```
var tLastDoc = querySnapshot[pageSize - 1];
tLastDoc.tDocId = querySnapshot[pageSize - 1].id;
```

And cache this tLastDoc in redux.

And in the snippet where paging happens, I check if the last document I am about to use for **startAfter** part of my query is actually a freshly fetched document snapshot or a non-snapshot fetched from redux like so:

```
if(lastDoc != null && typeof lastDoc.id === 'undefined'){
  //stripped snapshot. get the document snapshot and use it for paging
} else {
  //already a document snapshot, use it for paging
}
```

*Remember from the screenshots in the question above that an actual document snapshot will have an "id" property. If "id" is not defined, it is actually the 'stripped' document snapshot coming from redux.*

If it is a 'stripped' snapshot document coming from redux, I simply fetch the snapshot again from the firestore backend using the tDocId property I assigned above and use the returned document snapshot as my **startAfter** parameter.

This fetching of the last document from the firestore backend will only happen once each time the user re-launched the app to page the records using the cached lastDoc in the redux store. Then the paging will be used using the consecutive document snapshots retrieved at the end of each paging as long as the app is not backgrounded again.

Hope this helps.